# Elastic search with hadoop

Tags: elasticsearch, hadoop

Currently in my organization we are holding semi structured data in elastic search and we use queries for fast text search and aggregation, but we have other products which lie in other databases so we want to put all the data in a data lake like HDFS

So if I use HDFS as a data lake to hold raw data, how will use elastic search with it? I mean elastic search index data before using it, so is it possible to hold the data in the data lake , and then elastic search will query the data from the data lake directly without needing to store the data in elastic? or will i hold the data in the data lake then process it and store it again in elastic so it can index it?

to summarize, I want to know the concepts of elastic and hadoop intergation

Answer (score 0):

Both Spark and Hive offer Elasticsearch connectors; there's no need to export documents into HDFS, other than possibly backup functionality.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/reference.html

Comment: My intention was to put all my data in a centralized source such as HDFS ( data lake ) , but then again what would be the point of integrating with spark and hive ? I mean how does the integration really work ? or what would be the point of using spark and hive with elastic if my data is not on HDFS